# My closing parenthesis is throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to execute this query but I keep receiving error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Would you please look over my query? I believe with every SQL keyword I've added the appropriate parenthesis.

```
USE [db]
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @AlertDateTime date
      , @HostName  varchar(50)
      , @Program varchar(100)
      , @Event varchar(100)
      , @Entity varchar(50)
      , @Class tinyint
      , @Severity tinyint
      , @AlertMessage varchar(1024)
      , @SkipFlag char(1) 

select cast(getdate() as date)

IF EXISTS 

(SELECT * FROM SendAlertLog 

WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT SendAlertLog.Event  
    FROM SendAlertLog
    GROUP BY SendAlertLog.Event 
    HAVING COUNT (1) >= 2 
)
AND SendAlertLog.SkipFlag != 'Y' 
AND AlertDateTime <= DATEADD (mi,-30,@AlertDateTime)
)
```

I do not know what I am including or excluding wrong. Please help

Comment: did you missed begin ... end

Comment: Thank you Satya, using BEGIN END worked!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an if, but no statement to do if the expression is true.  You have

```
IF EXISTS(...)
```

But you need

```
IF EXISTS(...)
   DO_SOMETHING
```

Comment: Thank you! mhasan and user12861. I removed the IF EXISTS and replaced with BEGIN END.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one (without double usage of SendAlertLog) -

```
DECLARE @AlertDateTime DATE

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              cnt = COUNT(1)
            , SkipFlag = MAX(l.SkipFlag)
            , AlertDateTime = MAX(l.AlertDateTime)
        FROM dbo.SendAlertLog l
        GROUP BY l.[Event] 
    ) l
    WHERE cnt >= 2
        AND l.SkipFlag != 'Y' 
        AND l.AlertDateTime <= DATEADD(mi, -30, @AlertDateTime)
) BEGIN

    PRINT 'Do something'

END
```

Comment: Thank you but An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.:( I am very new to Database land.

Comment: This is a great way to eliminate redundancy in query writing and to control output view with IF statements.